# Ensure pop up dialog box pop ups wherever users page location?

Tags: html, css, popup

Hi I have the following Iframe and CSS, with current functionality, when I have a web page, with its content really long and users click feedback button the dialogue box pop ups at the top of the page and not wherever the users location is on the page, I was wondering how to ensure dialog box pops up wherever the user is located on the page?

Do we achieve this with CSS? looking for some help please?

```
<div id="MfpEmbed_Popup" style="width: 480px; height: 600px;"><div id="mfpembed_iconDiv"><img <iframe src=""id="MfpEmbed_Popup_Iframe"></iframe></div>


#MfpEmbed_Popup {
    z-index: 1000001;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `position: absolute` to `position: fixed` and set the top to 0.

(Better open the snippet in full screen)

```js
function open_popup(){
  var div = document.getElementById("MfpEmbed_Popup");
  div.style.opacity = "1";
}
```

```css
#MfpEmbed_Popup {
    z-index: 1000001;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
```

```html
<div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div><div><p>a long page</p></div>


<div style="position:fixed; right:0; bottom:0; z-index:1000000"><button onclick="open_popup()">click me to open popup</button></div>

<div id="MfpEmbed_Popup" style="width: 480px; height: 600px; z-index:10000"><div id="mfpembed_iconDiv">
  <p style="color: black;">Dialog</p>
</div>
```

Check this codepen I made:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Yuvix/pen/abNZNoM)

Answer (score 0):

Your should change

```
position: absolute;
```

to

```
position: fixed;
```

This change will ensure the dialog box pops up wherever the user is located on the page. The dialog will be centered in the middle of the page.